# Optimize hive query requesting data from two parition

Tags: hive, amazon-athena, presto

currently, I am using hive with s3 storage.

I have total 1000000 partitions right now. I am facing a problem where:

If I do:

Query execution time is less than 1 second.

```
select sum(metric) from foo where pt_partition_number = 'bar1'

select sum(metric) from foo where pt_partition_number = 'bar2'
```

But if I do

```
select sum(metric) from foo where pt_partition_number IN ('bar1','bar2')
```

The query is taking near about 30 seconds. I am thinking hive is doing directory scan in case of second query.

Is there a way to optimize query:
My request pattern always access two partition data.

Comment: does it give the same result for `pt_partition_number = 'bar1' and pt_partition_number = 'bar2'`

Comment: Try using OR instead of IN: WHERE pt_partition_number = 'bar1' OR pt_partition_number = 'bar2' ?

Comment: This should work the same, but i recall there was a problem in the past with IN predicate pushdown when there is a coercion (and here there is a coercion). Athena wraps Presto 0.172, so it misses a ton of improvements that were delivered over last year and a half. Why don't you try this on a regular Presto cluster? Either EMR or just Presto (https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07DKV5659) will do.

Comment: @leftjoin Or query also have same results. 
Will try on normal presto cluster.